# Inheritance and polymorphism in XSD

Tags: xml, inheritance, xsd

My question pretty much repeats [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106553/xsd-abstract-types-and-polymorphism), which did not receive any answers. Hope I have better luck.

I'd like to implement inheritance in XSD elements, in a way which supports both polymorphism in the xml, and regular OO inheritance in the classes generated from the XSD.

This is how the C# generated classes should look like (in a simplified example):

```
class Zoo{ private Animal _animal; }
abstract class Animal{ private int _someProperty; }
class Lion:Animal{ }
class Zebra:Animal{ }
```

And this is how the Xml should look like

```
<Zoo> <Lion /> </Zoo>
<Zoo> <Zebra /> </Zoo>
```

but not:

```
<Zoo> <Animal /> </Zoo>
```

I've tried using xs:extension, but it did not work the way I expected.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

[developerfusion.co.uk](http://quickstart.developerfusion.co.uk/quickstart/howto/doc/xmlserialization/XSDFromCls.aspx)
[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

The above article uses *xsd.exe* to go from a class (or class hierarchy) to an xsd schema. Have you tried this and checked if the outcome is acceptable?

I've also added an msdn article on that tool.

And yet another edit: a tool like Enterprise Architect (and similar ones) often has a feature to create an xsd starting from a class diagram (uml). See for example [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/xml_schema_generation.html).

Cheers,
Wim

Comment: Thanks Wim! I'm trying out your suggestions on a sample just to figure out what's the syntax I'm looking for. I would rather not use this reversal method for my real problem, since I've already written most of the xsd, plus it seems that the xsd tool needs the classes to have some attributes, which means a lot of tinkering for a pretty basic syntax question (I should hope :) ).